# How the way an android checkbox when it check then convert to string and insert into database?

Tags: android, arrays, json, checkbox

I have a little problem when adding a checkbox in my app project.

**How can I do the following?:**

- When a checkbox is selected it is changed to a string and can be inserted into a MySQL database.

---

**Here my mainactivity code**

```
private void addEmployee(){

    final String nama = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String pyg = editTextDesg.getText().toString().trim();
    final String tmpt = editTextSal.getText().toString().trim();
    final String tgl = Date.getText().toString().trim();
    final String jam = Waktu.getText().toString().trim();
    final Boolean email = Penting.isChecked();


    class AddEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Menambahkan...","Tunggu...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_NAMA,nama);
            params.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_PENYELENGGARA,pyg);
            params.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_TEMPAT,tmpt);
            params.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_TGL,tgl);
            params.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_JAM,jam);
            params.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_EMAIL, String.valueOf(email.equals("Penting")));

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(konfigurasi.URL_ADD, params);
            return res;
```

**and this my php code to insert into database**

```
<?php


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //Mendapatkan Nilai Variable
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $desg = $_POST['pyg'];
    $sal = $_POST['tmpt'];
    $tgl = $_POST['tgl'];
    $jam = $_POST['jam'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //Pembuatan Syntax SQL
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_pegawai (namaagenda,penyelenggara,tempat,tanggal,jam) VALUES ('$nama','$desg','$sal',str_to_date('".$tgl."', '%d-%m-%Y'),'$jam', '$email')";

    //Import File Koneksi database
    require_once('koneksi.php');

    //Eksekusi Query database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Berhasil Menambahkan Pegawai';
    }else{
        echo 'Gagal Menambahkan Pegawai';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Boolean email = Penting.isChecked();
```

This will return a true or false. true if checkbox is checked and false if not. use this true or false for getting data.

```
  String str=Penting.getText().toString()
```

String str will give the text that is given for the checkbox

Comment: It will work to read the checkbox text. I had used it may times. and even today in one of my Application to get the Educational Qualification of the  user

Comment: do i have wrong with my php code? because I have done what you suggest, and can not insert into db

Comment: yes it work thank you, but why is it false all filled? can you give me more suggest

Comment: I didnt understand what u mean.can u please elaborate it